# How to not add cell if the string in textfield in is empty?

Tags: swift

I am creating a todo list, and the problem is when I add empty string the cell is added now matter if user entered something or not. How to avoid empty cells?

{

1. Do homework
2. 
3. Do workout
   }

how to not create a cell if there is an empty string?

Comment: Don't focus on the cells, focus on the data. If there is no string, then that little bit of data doesn't exist as far as the table is concerned. Consider creating an array like `finalToDo` that only contains the strings with text in them and make that array your table's data source. This way, your table only sees the data that it cares about. Does that make sense?

Comment: @bsod yes! Thank you!

Comment: you can also set height 0 for empty strings

Answer (score 0):

u can just filter your data array which u are using inside the tableView like this:

```
 arr = arr.filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
```